# debugger syntax definition

Tags: debugging, lua, vim-syntax-highlighting, zerobrane

Zerobrane has a color scheme but also shows underlining (some solid, some dotted) when viewing a .lua file.
e.g.,

```
buttonMain.y = display.contentCenterY - ...
```

where `buttonMain` is dotted underline & "display" is solid underline (only the word `display`, not the `.content...` part.

It is probably trying to tell me something useful, but I cannot understand it.

Is there a source to describe the different formats, etc. and their meaning within the Zerobrane Corona debugger?

I looked in ZBS but did not see an explanation of this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

These are indicators that show the scope of a variable: global, local, masking, or masked. See the [FAQ](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-faq#what-are-the-dotted-and-dashed-lines-under-variable-names) and the [documentation](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-styles-color-schemes#indicators) for details. There is also a [blog post](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/scope-aware-variable-indicators-zerobrane-studio) that describes them with a screenshot.